# Infobip single sms service using guzzle in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sms, guzzle, infobip-api

I am trying to send sms with my laravel application. I have infobip testing account and using that details to sms sms but getting this error:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single` resulted in a        `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"requestError":{"serviceException":   {"messageId":"UNAUTHORIZED","text":"Invalid login details"}}}
```

**CODE:**

```
$data= '{  
       "from":"InfoSMS",
       "to":"923227124444",
       "text":"Test SMS."
    }';
    $userstring = 'myuserame:password';
    $id =base64_encode ( 'myuserame:password' );
    echo 'Basic '.$id;
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->post('https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single',array(
            'content-type' => 'application/json'
            ),['auth' =>  ['myusername', 'password']]);
    $request->setHeaders(array(
      'accept' => 'application/json',

      'authorization' => 'Basic '.$id,
      'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ));
    $request->setBody($data); #set body!
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
    echo $res->getBody();
    return $response;
```

The username and pssword are right as I tried to send direct text message from the site and its working there.

Can anyone help me with what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I tired solving the problem using curl and I got it working placing code for others.
Code:

```
$data_json = '{
       "from":"Infobip",
       "to":"9232271274444",
       "text":"test msg."
    }';
    $authorization = base64_encode('username:password');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json',"Authorization: Basic $authorization"));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    var_dump($response);
    curl_close($ch);*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass username / password as you read in the infobip api developer manuals.

Try this:

```
$authEncoded = base64_encode('myuserame:password');
$data = array(
    "from" => "InfoSMS",
    "to" => "923227124444",
    "text" => "Test SMS."
);
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single',
    array(
        'json' => $data,
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $authEncoded,
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        )
    )
);
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->send($request);
echo $response->getBody();
```

I can't test it myself right now so keep me updated if it worked or you get an error.

Comment: I was getting Request error in this but I tired solving it with curl. placing code here.